# How many ABIs does react-native support for Android?

Tags: android, react-native

In the default react-native Android application there is ndk filter. So, does it mean that react-native application is supported only for "armeabi-v7a" and "x86". Does other ABI are supported by react-native for Android ? Does this mean that if I go for react-native then some Android devices can't install my Android app?